# Test Es6 AngularJS Components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I am trying to test a component in my angularjs module with jest.
In my opinion it should be enough to test the Controller and not the whole component because the controller does all the work. so i am not quite sure if i need the whole angular-mock dependency or if i can just test the controller in some way

```
import template from './order.html';

export class OrderController {
  constructor($state, $stateParams, orderService) {
    'ngInject';
    this.$state = $state;
    this.$stateParams = $stateParams;

    this.dataService = orderService;
    this.price = this.dataService.getPrice();
    this.isOrderAllowed = this.dataService.getOrderAllowed();
  }

  goToCheck(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.$state.go('order.orderCheck');
  }
  $onInit() {}
}


let OrderComponent = {
  template: template,
  controller: OrderController,
  controllerAs: '$vm'
};

export default OrderComponent;
```